# Rails 3 Nested Resources Edit/Update Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wrapping my head around Nested Resources (awesome btw) and I have a question in regards to the Edit and Update actions in my controller.

My route is set up with the following:

```
resources :events do
 resources :people
end
```

In my People controller, I have the following for the New action:

```
 @event = current_user.events.find(params[:event_id])
 @person = @event.people.build
 @person.build_address
```

and for the Create action I have:

```
@event = current_user.events.find(params[:event_id])
@person = @event.people.build(params[:person])
```

This all works great.

I'm unsure of what I need to do for the Edit and Update actions though. Googling hasn't yielded any good links.

Here are my models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :address
   has_many :people
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :events
end
```

I basically want to make sure that when I edit a person, AR will update the correct event id and address id along with the person's details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model setup is incorrect. You have a

```
belongs_to
```

on either side of the Event-Address and the People-Address relationship. In a one-to-many relationship you need to have a

```
has_many
```

on 1 side and a

```
belongs_to
```

on the other side.

That apart from your controller's perspective its quite straight-forward to  setup your edit and update actions. Its just how you you setup the new and create actions.
Here's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) that talks about nested resources.

**Note**: Helping you with controller code would be easier if you correct your model relationships.

**UPDATE**

Your model relationships look fine. So now its pretty straightforward.  I hope the Railscast that I linked helped you out on nested resources.

Here's another useful resource on [Nested Resources](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

Comment: So does the Event and People model have belongs_to and the Address model has has_many?

Comment: Well thats a modeling decision that is left to you (Event could have many people or even the other way. It depends on your scenarios.). But the principle which I mentioned should be maintained.

Comment: Ok. I have updated my original post. Basically an event will have 1 address and a person will have 1 address.

Comment: Yes, the Railscast episode helped me figure it out. Thanks.